# Touch control for html5 game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been working on a simple html5 canvas game, and I'm trying to add touch controls for devices as well as keyboard input for desktops etc.
The keyboard controls are perfect: space bar is tapped to jump, and held for a longer jump.
I've added event listeners for touch control, which emulate the single tap of the spacebar, but I can't figure out how to recreate holding the space bar for longer jumps with the touch control. My keyboard code looks like this:

```
    // jump if not currently jumping or falling
if (KEY_STATUS.space && player.dy === 0 && !player.isJumping) {
  player.isJumping = true;
  assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
  jumpCounter = 12;

}

// jump higher if the space bar is continually pressed
if (KEY_STATUS.space && jumpCounter) {
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
  assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
}

jumpCounter = Math.max(jumpCounter-1, 0);

this.advance();
```

And that gets tracked with this code:

```
var KEY_CODES = {
32: 'space'

};
var KEY_STATUS = {};
for (var code in KEY_CODES) {
if (KEY_CODES.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
 KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[code]] = false;
 }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
e.preventDefault();
KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = true;
 }
};
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
var keyCode = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
if (KEY_CODES[keyCode]) {
e.preventDefault();
KEY_STATUS[KEY_CODES[keyCode]] = false;
 }
};
```

My new event listeners for touch screen devices looks like this:

```
 document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler);
 document.addEventListener("touchhold", touchHandler);
 document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler);
```

And then I have this function, which is more or less identical to the function for keyboard input, only 'e.touches' is referenced, rather than 'KEY_STATUS':

```
 function touchHandler(e) {
 if(e.touches && player.dy === 0 && !player.isJumping) {
  player.isJumping = true;
  assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
  jumpCounter = 12;
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  }
```

That function enables the little jump. If I include this 'if' statement, it enables multiple jumps:

```
  if (e.touches && jumpCounter) {
  player.dy = player.jumpDy;
  assetLoader.sounds.jump.play();
  }
```

...rather than enabling the player to perform the longer jump. Essentially, the player could tap to fly throughout the game, which I don't want! Is there a way to specify within the 'touchHandler()' function which kind of jump is being made ie. is the screen being tapped or held? Or would I need to write a separate function for that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: touchstart is the exact equivalent of keydown, touchend is the exact equivalent of keyup. Just use separate handlers that deal with the actual event type, like you did for keydown and keyup. Everything you need to fix this is already in your question.

Comment: Hi @Chris G, I thought as much but I'm too inexperienced to figure it out. If I write a 'document.ontouch...' function like the 'document.onkeydown..." one, do I then need to write variables like the KEY_CODES and KEY_STATUS ones? I tried to amend the 'touchHandler' function to 'touchHandlerStart' etc but that prevented the program from loading. Any advice would be greatly appreciated thnxs.

Comment: First of all, you need to separate your controls logic from your game logic. Here's how: http://jsbin.com/jogeyiyasa/edit?js,output At the top I'm defining the controls, `area` uses percent of the screen, from x1,y1 to x2,y2. Then a few helper functions and the handlers. At the bottom, in the tick() function, you can see how I'm changing the background color based on which button is down (touch the screen's upper half or bottom half, or press space/a). Multitouch isn't properly handled yet though.